# Doctrine-odm not aware of a MongoDB primary member change

Tags: apache, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm

Let's consider a `MongoDB replicaset` composed of 3 members (1 active primary and 2 secondaries) and:

1. the primary member disappears whereas requests issued from the "front" servers continues to arrive
2. a new primary is correctly elected within the remaining members

Now, the problem we are facing is that the requests still call the absent member as if it were still available and that a persistent connection was established between `Symfony2` and the replicaset.

At this stage, we are forced to restart `Apache` to reset all connections ... what we don't want, `Doctrine-odm` having to switch by itself.

Why does this occur?

Comment: This isn't doctrine but rather the PHP driver, what PHP driver is this and what version?

Comment: php5-mongo 5.4.19-1~dotdeb.1 (debian)

Comment: I am unaware of a 5.4 release: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/releases that sounds like the PHP release, can you get me the driver version?

Comment: Sorry, the MongoDB driver version is 1.4.3 (release date: 2013-08-15)

Comment: Is apache in fork mode rather than fcgi mode?

Comment: I don't know but I can tell that the mod_cgi and prefork modules are loaded.

Comment: @Sammaye, anyone, no idea then?

Comment: Not really, it works for me on Apache, the only thing I could have though of was that there was a bug with worker caching that meant it didn't try and grab new connections, you might be better off on the mongodb-user group for this since it is probably something you will need to talk to with the maintainers of the PHP driver me thinks